# Map all requests to subpaths of a script to the script itself

Tags: php, apache

I have a script at: http:://vis.setihub.org/dataset/index.php/

I want the server to let the script handle requests of the form: http:://vis.setihub.org/dataset/index.php/mysubpath/

I can use the PATH_INFO available in PHP to see what subpath was requested. I just don't know how to make the server send the request to the script in the first place instead of looking for the physical path.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, it's just:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

though the default setting should work for PHP scripts. See the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo).

Comment: @And Check the logs. You need `FileInfo` override if you're using it an .htaccess.